# Is there a name for the words at the beginning of a sentence which make it a question?

Tags: questions

Given the following sentences

> **Is** it Thursday Today?
>
> **Does** your dog smell?
>
> **Has** your Mother called?

Is there a particular name given to the emphasised words at the beginning of the sentence which make it a question?

If not is there a name for the process of turning a sentence into a question?

Answer (score 6):

The term describing these words is **[auxiliary verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb)**.

> a verb that adds functional or grammatical meaning to the clause in which it appears—for example, to express tense, aspect, modality, voice, emphasis, etc.

As for the process of turning a sentence into a question, I'm not aware of any specific term for it. I'd just say "forming an interrogative" or "converting into a question" or something similar.

That said, as deadrat and StoneyB rightly point out, what is happening here is called **subject-auxiliary inversion**; for example, the statement form of your first example would be "It is Thursday today.", while in question form the subject and verb are switched around so the question form begins "is it" instead.

Comment: No, interrogatives are *who*, *what*, *where*, *why*, etc.

Comment: Yes, but they're also did, has, is etc.

Comment: No, those are auxiliaries.

Comment: Ah, I thought they were still called interrogatives when used to form questions. I'll edit.

Comment: While you're at it, you might note that what's going on in the questions is subject-verb inversion, i.e., in a question, the declarative sentence order of subject then verb ("Today is Thursday.") is reversed ("Is today Thursday?").  I looked to see if there's a duplicate in the repository, but a brief look didn't find a good one.  So in the examples, it's not the initial words that's important; it's the order that puts that initial word first.

Comment: I've added a bit about that, and given you a shiny internet point for your contributions.

Comment: If it is a real subject-verb inversion, "He is playing" should be changed to "Is playing he?", not "Is he playing"? as the verb of the sentence is "playing", not "is". Copular *be* could be a verb and an auxiliary verb at the same time. For example, "You are not hungry, are you?", the second *are* is an auxiliary verb. Therefore, I think the *is* in "Is it Thursday today" is an auxiliary verb. +1)

Comment: @deadrat It's called subject-auxiliary inversion, not subject-verb inversion. Today *be* is generally treated as an 'auxiliary' in all uses, including 'lexical'; *have* is still in the process of drawing a bright line between auxiliary and lexical uses.

Comment: At this point I've edited the answer so much I don't think it's even mine any more, but thanks for the correction. I'll change it @StoneyB.

Comment: @Rathony StoneyB is correct. "Be" is always an auxiliary verb, even if it's the only verb in the clause. The OP's three examples all exhibit subject-auxiliary inversion.

Comment: @BillJ That is debatable and some grammar books have different views.I don't think the "is" in "The book is on the table" is an auxiliary verb as it clearly means "to exist". However, the "is" in "Is the book on the table" could be an auxiliary verb as it changes the indicative sentence to an interrogative sentence.

Comment: @Rathony I'm not sure I agree with you there: in your example sentence you're saying where the book is located, not where it exists. To wit, I couldn't replace that with "The book exists on the table." without sounding silly, but if I said "The book be on the table." I'd sound like a badass pirate. Pirates are better than silly people.

Comment: @Rathony In _The book is on the table_, the auxiliary "is"  inverts with the subject to form the interrogative _Is the book on the table_? Only auxiliary verbs invert to form interrogatives. Lexical verbs first require the insertion of the dummy auxiliary do".

Comment: @John Clifford Yes, but it's not the complement that dictates whether or not a verb is an auxiliary; it's the way the verb behaves. The positive _The book is on the table_ becomes interrogative _Is the book is on the table?_ by virtue of the inversion of the subject "The book"  and the verb "is", thus proving that "is" an auxiliary verb, not a lexical one. Only auxiliary verbs behave that way.

Comment: @BillJ Does that mean I don't get to be a badass pirate? :(

Comment: I know it sounds silly, but it was used to emphasize its function and meaning are different. @BillJ The verb *be* is an extraordinary case where it doesn't require another auxiliary to make an interrogative sentence. The two "is'" in "He is happy" and "He is playing" are different "be". I don't agree the first "is" is an auxiliary verb while the second is definitely an auxiliary verb.

Comment: @John Clifford Haha!

Comment: @Rathony The evidence is also clear with negatives. Lexical verbs require the insertion of the dummy auxiliary "do", as in _He doesn't seem insane_,  but auxiliaries do not: compare _He isn't acting strangely_ in which "is" is undisputedly an auxiliary with _He isn't insane_ . Neither requires the insertion of dummy "do". But I agree that traditional grammar does not treat "be" as an auxiliary verb. Oh well ...